# Can we break the permission inheritance for a SharePoint custom list item + get all the permission assignments, using GraphAPI instead SharePointAPI

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, power-automate, flow, microsoft-graph

Inside our Power automate Cloud flow we have these actions:

1. Break Permission inheritance
2. Get all Permission assignments
3. Remove all Permission assignments

as follow:

[image]

[image]

So can we perform all/some of those actions using Graph API instead of SharePoint API? since Graph API is more future proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not yet possible using Microsoft Graph APIs.

Microsoft graph APIs does not these operations yet:

1. Breaking Permission inheritance
2. Fetching all Permission assignments
3. Removing all Permission assignments

Only below methods are supported now:

[image]

**Documentation**: [listItem resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/listitem?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: but based on Microsoft recommendation that SharePoint aPI is considered legacy compared to the newer Graph API , am i correct? –

Comment: Yes, but SharePoint APIs will not be deprecated (at least any time soon). Microsoft Graph does not support "all" operations supported by SharePoint APIs yet.